# Is there anyway to leave a space station without your ship?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Is it possible to get off of the space station other than by flying out in your ship?

Comment: Lol, funny question, you wanna try to float in space "Gravity"-style? :-)

Comment: I just like trying to go places the game doesn't want me to :P. Any time I get artificially boxed in somewhere I immediately try to find a way out haha.

Comment: If you find a way let me know, curious to try this as well to see what happens :-)

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks I will do :p

Answer (score 3):

The only 2 ways I've tried so far don't work.

1. Walking, you can walk all the way to the end of the runway (right word?), but there's a wall at the end
2. Surfing, if you stand on a ship once it's landed, it wont take off with you on top, and it appears when the ships are flying they don't have a hitbox.

Only other thing I can think of is to try and glitch out, but I've not come across anywhere to do that yet.

Comment: Did you try a jetpack dash yet? Might be a thought? (Melee whilst sprinting and immediately hit your jetpack for a lateral boost in speed*) 
* Might cause exosuit damage ;)

Comment: I don't think you can melee on the space station :(

Comment: @DavidYell Tom is right, you can't melee or shoot inside a space station. Intergalactic law or something.

Comment: With the new update, if you have a base, you can take the teleporter that's in the room on the right (after you ship lands and rotates).  However, your ship will spawn somewhere near your base.

Answer (score 2):

There is now.  I don't remember if it was part of Pathfinder or Next, but there's a teleporter that allows you to travel between other teleporters (Space Stations and ones you can build in your own bases).

I believe you need to reach a certain point in the storyline to unlock the teleportation network.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you were asking, but if you're looking for space walks in general, one way is to fall off of a frigate. Not sure if freighters and frigate fleets existed before NEXT, but at least as of NEXT, you can fall off of a frigate landing pad after you land on it (which will kill you via cold damage in just a few seconds).